# How to restrict the <h:inputtextarea> to maximum length can type by user?

Tags: jsf

Does anybody know how to stop the user to allow max number of characters in  in JSF application??

Any attribute to set maxLength?

Comment: It does prevents when I click submit button it validates by f:validateLength. But I want it to prevent me while I was typing itself. So, I think both are not same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my experience, `maxLength` attribute  will not work for `<h:inputTextarea>`, so instead you can use either javascript function by “onkeyup” attribute and call that method.

or

You can use `<ace:textAreaEntry>` tag with `maxLength` attribute by updating to icefaces-ace-3.2.0.jar.